# JAWS Screen Reader reading issues in Windows 10 IE browser

Tags: jaws-screen-reader

I am getting JAWS Screen Reader issues only in Windows 10 IE browser version 10.

When i am focusing from one section to another section, JAWS Screen Reader is reading previous section's first element then reading current element.

Has anyone experienced these issues? Please let me know. And i am using bootstrap 4 grid system for this application.

Comment: Can you explain "When i am focusing from one section to another section"?  What do you mean by "section"?  A literal `<section>` element?  Are you "focusing" by navigating with the JAWS region/landmark shortcut key `R` or are you moving the focus with `tab` key?  When the "first element" of the previous section is read, is it the first interactive element or just the first child element in the DOM?  If you could post some code, that would help.

Comment: Here section means, i have a container, in that i have two columns like left and right. When i am focusing from left column to right column, there JAWS reader is reading left columns first child element then reading current element. that's it. And thank you for supporting.

Comment: you still haven't answered the questions.  what do you mean by "focusing"?  are you tabbing with the keyboard or are you navigating the dom using the screen reader keys?  please be specific on what exactly you're doing.  and what are your containers?  there is no `<container>` element.  again, be specific.  is it a `<div>` with a `role`?  does it have an `aria-label`?  when you say 'left column' and 'right column', does that mean you have tables with columns?  this is not normally a problem so the issue might be in your code.  it might help if you post your code.

Comment: Yes, i am tabbing with Keyboard. Containers means, <div class="container">, in that i took two divs one is  <div class="col-md-9"> means left column,  <div class="col-md-3"> means right column when i am focusing from left column to right column using keyboard, JAWS screen reader reading left columns first element which is anchor, then it is reading current element.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable layout. If the element in the right column is (accidentally) pointing to the left column, that could cause the problem. For example, if you have an `aria-labelledby` in the right that references an ID from the left. That’s about as far as I can guess without seeing a code sample.

Comment: Okay, but i didn't use aria-labelledby. Still having that issue. I want to resolve that issue. Can you show solution for this issue? And thing i am getting this issue in Windows 10 IE only.

Comment: I'm done commenting unless you can post your code.  It's a waste of time to guess what's going on.